# jQuery inView with anime.js only fire once

Tags: javascript, jquery, anime.js

I'm making an animation atm and wanted to animate a text once when I scroll there. Here is the code. The code works all fine I don't know why it won't work here. But I saw that the text fires every time I scroll there. How can I prevent this? So it only fires once?

```js
var fadeUpNormal = anime.timeline({
  loop: false,
  autoplay: false,
}).add({
  targets: '.fade-up-normal',
  translateY: [100,0],
  opacity: [0,1],
  translateZ: 0,
  easing: 'easeOutExpo',
  duration: 1400,
  delay: 1000;
});

$('.scroll-trigger').on('inview', function(event, isInView) {
  if (isInView) {
    fadeUpNormal.play();
  } else {}
});
```

```css
div {
  background-color: #444;
  height: 1000px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}


#wwrp1 {
  color: black;
  font-size: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/protonet-jquery.inview/1.1.2/jquery.inview.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.1/anime.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div>
    <p class="fade-up-normal scroll-trigger" id="wwrp1">This is an example</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: in your snippet there is no animation

Comment: @Greg-- Yea, I saw that too. But I don't know why. For me all works fine and its the same code. Trying to fix it!

Comment: did you try to add global variable `let isPlayed = false`
And then change 'inview' event to `if (isInView && !isPlayed){isPlayed = true...}` ?

Comment: @Greg-- Thanks for your help, Greg. But I managed out the solution! I just needed to change .on to .one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is just to use `.one('inview')` for `.on('inview')`. That was my bad!